# Shortest path length when edge length is limited

Tags: probability-theory, random-graphs, geometric-probability, probabilistic-method

$N$ nodes are uniformly distributed in a square whose side length is $1$.
There exists an undirected edge between two nodes, if and only if the distance between them is less than or equal to $r$.
Here we set a source $s$ and a destination $t$ in this square, and the distance between them is $d$.
Now I want to find a shortest path from $s$ to $t$, that is, more precisely, the expectation of the path length from $s$ to $t$. 
Note that $r=\Theta\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log N}{N}}\right)$, and it can ensure that the graph is connected. 
$d$ might be a constant or a variable.
Intuitively, the expectation of path length is $O(d)$.
I refer to many papers, Continuous Time Markov Chain is proposed to solve it. But they are aimed at the complete graph which does not apply to this case. Would you please provide me some idea to solve  this problem ? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your comment claiming that the graph is connected. For example we can have $1$ point close to a first corner of the square and all the other points close to a second corner.

Comment: When $d\leq t$, $s$ and $t$ are connected so the path length is exactly $d$. Or did I misunderstood the question?